# Libreoffice .docx startup warning message

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

whenever I open a .docx using libreoffice file I receive the below warning.
[image]

How can I remove or rectify whatever the problem or trigger is?

**Details**: I installed libreoffice using `sudo apt install libreoffice`

- LibreOffice 7.0.5.2 00 (Build:2)
- Ubuntu 20.10 / (Groovy Gorilla)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ceaf5043-5694-4641-a7e0-cbcca7ac63ce/table-column-limit-and-how-this-is-calculated?forum=worddev

Comment: are you sure it is a docx and not an xlsx? does the document open with all rows and columns? If so I would suggest to check if any of the higher columns has a character in it triggering all the extra columns and save it without this column or to remove all the columns from where you stopped.